# Why does the Logitech SetPoint update seem to hang?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, updates, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

I've just gotten a new Logitech Wireless Wave Combo MK550 mouse and keyboard.  I pulled it in, and have installed the software that came on the CD, which is SetPoint 6.15.

After installing it, it said that it had an update, so I started the installation for that.  Now it's at a point where it says,

```
"Approximately 30 seconds remaining..."
```

Except it has been that way for 30 minutes, not 30 seconds.  So, what's going on?

I'm installing this on a Windows 7 Home Premium system, 64-bit OS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem installing 6.3 from the internet.

Comment: I had the same problem. It finally finished, after 60 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why it would be hanging if it had already started (if it hadn't started at all it could have been a firewall blocking it from even connecting).

I would suggest canceling the update and downloading the latest version from Logitech and installing from there rather than updating from the CD version.

If you don't want to download I'd try canceling and doing the update again. Either way if it's been hanging for ages chances are that it won't start up again by itself, so you'll probably have to cancel the update anyway.

Comment: +1 for downloading straight from the manufacturer's Web site as it guarantees you the latest version of the software/driver.

Comment: It finally finished, but MAN, it took a long time!

Answer (score 1):

After I had tried several times with the auto-updater and with the downloaded "full installer" I finally found how to complete the procedure.

While the UI hangs at "approximately 30 seconds remaining..." just exit the system tray updater.

This magically unlocks the installer and it runs to completion.